# Как удалить cookie в yii2

Tags: yii2, cookie

Пробую удалить куку так:

```
$cityCookie = Yii::$app->request->cookies[self::COOKIE_CITY_ID];            
$cityCookie->expire = -1;
$cityCookie->path = '/';
$cityCookie->value = null;
```

не работает.

В то время как:

```
setcookie(self::COOKIE_CITY_ID, null, -1, '/');
```

работает.

Answer (score 1):

Из официальной [документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html):

```
$cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;
// add a new cookie to the response to be sent
$cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
    'name' => 'language',
    'value' => 'zh-CN',
]));
// remove a cookie
$cookies->remove('language');
```

Вы пытаетесь удалить куку из запроса(`request`), а он доступен только для чтения, если хотите удалить куку то вам нужен ответ(`response`).

Comment: remove не работает

Comment: У меня этот код работает - удаляется кука из браузера. Вы можете так же попробовать unset($cookies['language']).